# How to get a text direction given a LatLng?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

having a LatLng is possible to get a text direction like this?

```
Av del Cid, 25, Valencia, España
```

It must be free of charge. Can't find any info about this.

For example, this is the LatLng:

```
LatLng valenciaLatLng = new LatLng(39.46427454569313, -0.37839918979489084);
```

It should be something similar to this:

```
String direction = valenciaLatLng.getDirection();
```

Does exists something for doing this?

Comment: `android.location.Geocoder`?

Comment: *"Reverse geocoding is the process of transforming a (latitude, longitude) coordinate into a (partial) address. The amount of detail in a reverse geocoded location description may vary, for example one might contain the full street address of the closest building, while another might contain only a city name and postal code"*